# Proving the existence of a sequence of polynomials that converges to a resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis

For my homework assignment i have to proof the following assertion:

For a $A \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and for any $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence of polynomials $p_n \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lim\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}p_n(A)=(A-z)^{-1}$.

To do so I thought it might be necessary to distinguish the cases $|z|>||A||$ and $|z|\leq ||A||$ and then to use the Neumann series, but I don't really know how to start. I really want to try this on my own, but I would be really greatful for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

You idea is good. If $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R},$ then $z$ is in the resolvent set of $A$ (since $A$ is self-adjoint). Then,

$$(z-A)^{-1}=\frac{1}{z}\left(I-\frac{1}{z}A\right)^{-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{z^{n+1}}.$$ The partial sums are a sequence of polynomials in $A$, and they converge to the resolvent.

Comment: thank you very much, that really helped! :) i think now i will manage it!

Comment: I have only one question: where does the n! come from? using the Neumann series I get the same sum without it.

Comment: My mistake (was doing something with exponentials earlier), fixed!